# Prometheus 2.x Limit Memory Usage

Tags: prometheus

Basically I am looking for a equivalent of 1.x storage.local.target-heap-size.

I have a prometheus app(running in a 6 core, 32G box) that pulls about host metrics from 2000 VMs. Scrape interval 5mins.

Within few mins my RAM usage increases up to 29-30GBs and later in 10-15mins, it dies with OOM or server is Unavailable from UI.

Any way we can tell prometheus to use a defined max RAM ?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You can't set a maximum memory usage for Prometheus.

But, you can remediate the memory issue by tunning Prometheus TSDB or Horizontal scaling it.

Promtheus TSDB tunning:

1. Increase scrape intervals to reduce data volume.
2. Keep only essential metrics and labels.
3. Use `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` to shorten data retention.
4. Summarize detailed metrics with recording rules.
5. Adjust `--storage.tsdb.max-block-duration` and `--storage.tsdb.min-block-duration` to manage memory.
6. Offload data to external storage solutions.